# Mounting a blob container’s contents as a drive in a VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I’ve scoured the ‘net trying to find an authoritative answer to what would seem like a basic capability question, but haven’t found one. I’ve created an Azure Storage Account which contains a blob container with various blobs I’ve created (which are database extract .BACPAC files from an Azure SQL Database server). I’ve now created a VM with SQL Server on it and would like to use those .BACPAC files to instantiate a copy of those databases on my VM.  However, it seems that a) you cannot attach non-.VHD blob containers as disks to a VM, b) there’s no functionality in the portal to “convert” an existing non-.VHD blob container into a .VHD, and c) there’s no way to copy files (EDIT: *using the portal*) from a blob container into an existing .VHD.  **Is all of this accurate?  If so, how does (or can) one mount or move data between blob containers and VMs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a) you cannot attach non-.VHD blob containers as disks to a VM

This is correct. You can only mount a Page Blob (that too a VHD) as a disk to a VM.

> b) there’s no functionality in the portal to “convert” an existing
>   non-.VHD blob container into a .VHD

Correct. Currently portal does not have this functionality. However do take a look at [zud.io](http://zud.io) which has this feature. It allows you to convert a block blob into page blob.

> c) there’s no way to copy files from a blob container into an existing
>   .VHD

Well, this you can do as long as you're able to mount that VHD as a drive. Once the VHD is mounted as a drive, you can download blobs from a blob container and save it into that VHD.

Comment: Ah, I think I should have been more precise in my third question - as I meant to ask if there was a way to copy files from a blob container into an existing VHD _using the portal alone_. I guess I'm off to brush up on my Azure Powershell skills.

Comment: I think there's some confusion. A blob container is like a folder and when you mount a VHD, it also acts like a folder. Do you want to copy blobs (or in other words files) from a blob container to a VHD so that your VHD contains many files? Unfortunately portal today provides somewhat limited functionality so you can't do it through portal alone.

Comment: Exactly - I used the term "files" when I should have said "blobs". This seems like a basic use case that the portal could easily support and would make simple admin tasks involving data that needs to move between VMs and other Azure services quite a bit easier.